# R ggplot points and color by groups: show multiple color if a point is in multiple groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to color my points by group and trying to see if there's a way in ggplot to have a point filled with two or more colors if that point belongs to more than one group.

My example dataset looks like this:

```
df1<-data.frame("lat"=c(0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20),
            "long"=c(100,110,120,120,100,110,110,120,100,100,100,110,110,120),
            "type"=c("A","B","A","B","C","A","C","A","A","B","C","B","C","B"))
```

If you look at the dataset, you can see that some points only have one `type`, while others have multiple `types` (for instance, at `lat=0` and `long=120`, `type=A,B`).

My plot right now looks like this:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=df1$lat,y=df1$long,col=df1$type))+geom_point(shape=1)
```

This colors each `lat` and `long` point with `type`, but at `lat=0` and `long=120` I only see type B color because it overwrote type A color.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a point have two boundaries (inner boundary with type A color and outer boundary with type B color), or if I can divide the boundary into two so that left half of it shows type A color and the right half of it shows type B color, or any other method that would have each point show multiple colors if they have more than one type.

I'd prefer being able to draw multiple boundaries for sake of visualization but really any other suggestions or insight would be really helpful!

Comment: As an aside: [Don't use `$ in aes()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2693). Do `ggplot(df1,aes(x=lat,y=long,col=type)) + …`

Comment: maybe try geom_point(shape=1,alpha=0.2).. this way you can see overlapping points (I think). and you don't need to use "$", just call aes(x=lat,y=long,col=type)

Comment: If use the "alpha" aesthetic and set the value <1, it will become slight transparent thus seeing both points.

Comment: Not really, it just makes it harder for me to see both colors. Also thanks for pointing out to not use "$", I'm so used to basic plotting at R at this point and that became a habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a new variable to your data and passing that as the size:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(lat, long) %>% 
  arrange(type, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(size = row_number(), n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(size = max(n) - size) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lat, y = long, color = type, size = size)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 8), guide = FALSE)
```

[image]